# Implementing a PriorityQueue Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

Here is my implementation of a PriorityQueue algorithm. I have a feeling that my pop function is wrong. But I am not sure where exactly it is wrong. I have checked multiple times on where my logic went wrong but it seems to be perfectly correct(checked with CLRS pseudo code).

```
class PriorityQueue:
"""Array-based priority queue implementation."""
def __init__(self):
    """Initially empty priority queue."""
    self.queue = []
    self.min_index = None

def parent(self, i):
    return int(i/2)

def left(self, i):
    return 2*i+1

def right(self, i):
    return 2*i+2

def min_heapify(self, heap_size, i):
    #Min heapify as written in CLRS
    smallest = i
    l = self.left(i)
    r = self.right(i)
    #print([l,r,len(self.queue),heap_size])

    try:
        if l <= heap_size and self.queue[l] < self.queue[i]:
            smallest = l
        else:
            smallest = i
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        if r <= heap_size and self.queue[r] < self.queue[smallest]:
            smallest = r

    except IndexError:
        pass

    if smallest != i:
        self.queue[i], self.queue[smallest] = self.queue[smallest], self.queue[i]
        self.min_heapify(heap_size, smallest)

def heap_decrease_key(self, i, key):
    #Implemented as specified in CLRS
    if key > self.queue[i]:
        raise ValueError("new key is larger than current key")

    #self.queue[i] = key

    while i > 0 and self.queue[self.parent(i)] > self.queue[i]:
        self.queue[i], self.queue[self.parent(i)] = self.queue[self.parent(i)], self.queue[i]
        i = self.parent(i)

def __len__(self):
    # Number of elements in the queue.
    return len(self.queue)

def append(self, key):
    """Inserts an element in the priority queue."""
    if key is None:
        raise ValueError('Cannot insert None in the queue')
    self.queue.append(key)
    heap_size = len(self.queue)
    self.heap_decrease_key(heap_size - 1, key)

def min(self):
    """The smallest element in the queue."""
    if len(self.queue) == 0:
        return None
    return self.queue[0]

def pop(self):
    """Removes the minimum element in the queue.

    Returns:
        The value of the removed element.
    """
    if len(self.queue) == 0:
        return None
    self._find_min()
    popped_key = self.queue[self.min_index]
    self.queue[0] = self.queue[len(self.queue)-1]
    del self.queue[-1]
    self.min_index = None
    self.min_heapify(len(self.queue), 0)
    return popped_key

def _find_min(self):
    # Computes the index of the minimum element in the queue.
    #
    # This method may crash if called when the queue is empty.
    if self.min_index is not None:
        return
    min = self.queue[0]
    self.min_index = 0
```

Any hint or input will be highly appreciated

Comment: What evidence do you have that anything is wrong, even if you don't know the cause or how to fix it?

Comment: Add some input so that it can be analysed further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that the `parent` function is wrong. As it should do the opposite from the `left` and `right` methods, you should first subtract 1 from `i` before halving that value:

```
def parent(self, i):
    return int((i-1)/2)
```

Other things to note:

- You don't really have a good use for the member `self.min_index`. It is either 0 or `None`, and the difference is not really used in your code, as it follows directly from whether the heap is empty or not. This also means you don't need the method `_find_min`, (which in itself is strange: you assign to `min`, but never use that). Any way, drop that method, and the line where you call it. Also drop the line where you assign `None` to `self.min_index`, and the only other place where you *read* the value, just use 0.
- You have two ways to protect against index errors in the `min_heapify` method: `<= heapsize` and a `try` block. The first protection should really have `<` instead of `<=`, but you should use only one way, not two. So either test the less-than, *or* trap the exception.
- The `else` block with `smallest = i` is unnecessary, because at that time `smallest == i`.
- `min_heapify` has a first parameter that *always* receives the full size of the heap. So it is an unnecessary parameter. It would also not make sense to ever call this method with another value for it. So drop that argument from the method definition and all calls. And then define `heap_size = len(self.queue)` as a local name in that function
- In `heap_decrease_key` you commented out the assignment `#self.queue[i] = key`, which is fine as long as you never call this method to really *decrease* a key. But although you never do that from "inside" the class, the user of the class may well want to use it in that way (since that is what the method's name is suggesting). So better uncomment that assignment.
- With the above changes, your instance would only have `queue` as its data property. This is fine, but you could consider to let `PriorityQueue` inherit from `list`, so that you don't need this property either, and can just work with the list that you inherit. By consequence, you should then replace `self.queue` with `self` throughout your code, and you can drop the `__init__` and `__len__` methods, since the `list` implementation of those is just what you need. A bit of care is needed in the case where you want to call a `list` original method, when you have overridden it, like `append`. In that case use `super().append`.

With all of the above changes applied:

```
class PriorityQueue(list):
    """Array-based priority queue implementation."""
    def parent(self, i):
        return int((i-1)/2)

    def left(self, i):
        return 2*i+1

    def right(self, i):
        return 2*i+2

    def min_heapify(self, i):
        #Min heapify as written in CLRS
        heap_size = len(self)
        smallest = i
        l = self.left(i)
        r = self.right(i)

        if l < heap_size and self[l] < self[i]:
            smallest = l
        if r < heap_size and self[r] < self[smallest]:
            smallest = r

        if smallest != i:
            self[i], self[smallest] = self[smallest], self[i]
            self.min_heapify(smallest)

    def heap_decrease_key(self, i, key):
        #Implemented as specified in CLRS
        if key > self[i]:
            raise ValueError("new key is larger than current key")

        self[i] = key

        while i > 0 and self[self.parent(i)] > self[i]:
            self[i], self[self.parent(i)] = self[self.parent(i)], self[i]
            i = self.parent(i)

    def append(self, key):
        """Inserts an element in the priority queue."""
        if key is None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot insert None in the queue')
        super().append(key)
        heap_size = len(self)
        self.heap_decrease_key(heap_size - 1, key)

    def min(self):
        """The smallest element in the queue."""
        if len(self) == 0:
            return None
        return self[0]

    def pop(self):
        """Removes the minimum element in the queue.

        Returns:
            The value of the removed element.
        """
        if len(self) == 0:
            return None
        popped_key = self[0]
        self[0] = self[-1]
        del self[-1]
        self.min_heapify(0)
        return popped_key
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `parent` function is already wrong.

The root element of your heap is stored in array index 0, the children are in 1 and 2. The parent of 1 is 0, that is correct, but the parent of 2 should also be 0, whereas your function returns 1.

Usually the underlying array of a heap does not use the index 0, instead the root element is at index 1. This way you can compute parent and children like this:

```
parent(i): i // 2
left_child(i): 2 * i
right_child(i): 2 * i + 1
```